# Display FlatList Horizontally in A Schedule-Like Scroll View Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have an example of what the component should look like below. It is a schedule-like screen that has a scroll view (vertically) to go between time stamps and a FlatList to scroll horizontally between items. Imagine this as a week-timetable of a gym that has all events written down by day in each column.

What would be the best approach to link the time in the scroll view to the data elements in each of the FlatList's column? I just want to understand this in theory first, before writing any code.

[image: Example]

Answer (score 0):

Could be several ways to achieve something like this, a mandatory thing  you will have to do is a **loop**, in order to get each item data and render it. Probably you will fetch some backend data, coming as `objects`, i.e:

```
const DATA = [{ a: 1 }, { b: 2 }, { c: 3 }];

render() {
  return DATA.map(d => <MyFancyBox>{d}</MyFancyBox>);
}
```

Comment: Yes, I get that, but how would it be working in terms of layout. Let's say an event linking to the time so it appears at the correct height on the scroll view matching the time stamp?

Comment: So, you can get your data sorted by time stamp from the backend or you can use a JS function to sort your data like: `array.sort((a, b) => new Date(b.date) - new Date(a.date));`